# Firestore compound query - combining not-in and inequality?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to perform a compound query combining an inequality `<` and `not-in`

```
collection("somecollection)
.where("field1", "<", somevalue)
.where("field2", "not-in", [value1,value2,value3]
```

Looking at the [documented queries limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) in Firestore this should be possible

But I get the following error:

> FirebaseError: Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<,
> <=, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality
> filters on 'field1' and 'field1'

So is it that in addition to its own limitations, not-in also has the limitations of the != operator?

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=)
> comparisons must all filter on the same field.

That would be quite a bummer...

I am using the web client v8.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`not-in` is considered an inequality comparison, so it can't be combined with other inequality operators.

If you found the documentation confusing or incomplete on the matter, I suggest using the "send feedback" button at the top of the page.  You could also file an issue on GitHub for the particular client SDK you're using in order to let the authors know that the error message was confusing or incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

a little late, but have this problem now, so as you know firebase has the limitation that when "comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field" this when using "where" and "orderBy" so the way i work around what just retrieve the list and then in my code sort the list base in the field i want, it work nice

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution will retrieve more documents than the one you want. It'll increase the cost

Comment: That is true, its not the perfect solution but the one i find at that precise moment